# Apply sizeForItemAt to only one collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using sizeForItemAt to set the cell size for ONE view controller, but it seems that I have to return a result also for the other CollectionViews, the problem is that I don't have the size value for the others since it is defined in the storyboard. I'm trying this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if categorie_cv == collectionView {
        let size: CGSize = categorie[indexPath.row].size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
        return CGSize(width: size.width + 40.0, height: categorie_cv.bounds.size.height)
    } else if collectionView == risultati {

        return THIS VALUE IS SET IN THE STORYBOARD 
    } else {
        return THIS VALUE IS SET IN THE STORYBOARD
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can not tell it to automatically use the intrinsic size of the element derived from its layout.

However if your layout would really allow for the intrinsic size to be configured non-ambiguously through AutoLayout/it's content, you can call `UIView.intrinsicContentSize`, possibly mixing with `layoutIfNeeded` call. I am not positive that this solution is 100% working though.

If I were you I would seek not the way to assign a delegate and implement `sizeForItemAt` but rather do define this size ALSO in the matters of the cell itself.

And by the way, actually, it's a bit of "will turn out NOT as you expected it to" to let the cells to determine their their content size. This can be very helpful and logical with UITableView, but layout calculation in case of UICollectionView is better to be determined by simpler, calculative approach.

That is, it's cheap to compute the width to be half of bounds width of `collectionView` and equal to height - rather then let the content freely layout itself using very dynamic content-compression rules and constraint priority evaluation. Typically, having all cells have absolutely nothing in common in terms of their aspect ratios, widths OR heights will really tend to output the undesirable results.